# Gradle add tar file to tar file not producing correct results

Tags: linux, gradle, tar

Never mind WHY I want to do this, I am just trying to emulate a legacy system.

I wish to use Gradle (v2.10) to package a tar file within a tar file.

Here is my build.gradle script:

```
task tar1(type: Tar) {
    extension 'tar'
    archiveName 'tar1.tar'
    dirMode 0755
    fileMode 0644
    into ('/') {
        from ('src/files')
    }
}

task tar2(type: Tar, dependsOn: 'tar1') {

    extension 'tar'
    archiveName 'tar2.tar'
    dirMode 0755
    fileMode 0644
    into ('/') {
        from (project.distsDir) {
            include{'tar1.tar'}
        }
    }
}
```

My build command is `gradle clean tar2`

For some reason I cannot fathom the Tar task is adding a 0 length tar2.tar file to tar2.tar:

```
~/example$ tar -tvf build/distributions/tar2.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               0 2016-02-03 11:40 tar2.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           10240 2016-02-03 11:40 tar1.tar
```

I only want tar1.tar to exist in tar2.tar.

What am I doing incorrectly or is this a bug in the Gradle Tar task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

replace this:

```
    from (project.distsDir) {
        include{'tar1.tar'}
    }
```

with:

```
from tar1.outputs
```

You can also drop the dependsOn: 'tar1' As a side note the tar1 will still exist unless you clean it up somehow.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick.  Did you mean "As a side note ..."?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the misspelling. I have too many keyboards at work so half the time I am in an awkward position when typing stuff up for stack.

Comment: Ha.  For a while I assumed you were not a native English-speaker and was trying mightily to suss out your meaning - until I took a look at your name.  By the way, if I could upvote you twice here, I would.  Your solution is extremely cool.  As you can tell, I'm a gradle newby.

Comment: I've been using it for well over 6 months and I still feel like a n00b :D I actually have a question about it posted up on stack right now. :)